# Conditional Mysql order by query

Tags: mysql

I can't understand conditional mysql order by. Kindly help us.  This is the order by query **order by  if(salary > 0 or id is null or id = '', 1,0), id desc, salary**.

Comment: So what's your question exactly?

Comment: You have a syntax error in there.

Comment: The query is executed correctly & the return data also correct. What's my question is I don't understand that query & how it's work ? @amallard

Answer (score 0):

Could you need this syntax

```
order by  if( (salary > 0 or id is null or id = '' ), 1, 0), id desc, salary
```

Comment: I hope that OP say something .. I believe that this warning was related to how he used IF.. so the answer  could be useful